# Converting BibLaTeX entry types

Tags: biblatex, emacs

I have a large biblatex file containing not only `@articles`, but also PhD theses as `@phdthesis` entries and Master's and Bachelor's theses as `@misc` entries.  I would like to use [RefManageR](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RefManageR/versions/1.3.0) to extract the numbers of papers and theses by type for different years.

Thus I need to do the the following:

1. Decide on whether to use `@phdthesis`, `@mathesis`, and `@bathesis`, or rather just use `@thesis` with an appropriate `type` attribute.
2. Make the appropriate changes in the bibtex file.  This can obviously only be semi-automatic, since I will have to inspect the `@misc` entries in order to decide the type.

Is there a prevailing opinion regarding the first step?

Does anyone have any good suggestions about how to achieve the second step?  The simple replacement I can do easily within Emacs, but adding the `type` attribute seems more difficult (perhaps a reason to avoid the `@thesis` approach?).

Comment: Since the page you linked to says RefManageR supports `biblatex`, I'm failing to understand why you need to convert anything at all (I'm not acquainted with RefManageR though). Can't you just import the data and handle the queries you want to do on R's side?

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning on using `biblatex` (only), it is more natural to use `@thesis` together with `type`. `@thesis` is listed in §2.1.1 *Regular Types* of [the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), whereas `@phdthesis` and `@mastersthesis` are type aliases (§2.1.2 *Type Aliases*) that are mapped to `@thesis` by the backend (Biber or BibTeX). Internally on the LaTeX side `biblatex` only knows `@thesis`. (This can sometimes lead to confusion, see e.g. https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1180, that can be avoided if one exclusively thinks in terms of `@thesis`.)

If you want your `.bib` file to remain compatible with BibTeX styles, you should probably stick to `@phdthesis` and `@mastersthesis`. These are the types listed in [`btxdoc`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf), which means that they are supported by the base BibTeX styles (`plain` and friends) and probably the vast majority of contributed styles. (There is no guarantee that contributed styles support all entry types and fields in the way `btxdoc` describes, but most do.)

Note that in any case neither the `biblatex` standard data model nor the BibTeX base styles know an entry type `@bathesis` (or similar). `biblatex` would, however, support `@thesis`+`type = {bathesis},` (see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/660).